# ReactJS inline all CSS url images to data uri

Tags: css, reactjs, data-uri

I'm working to my first ReactJS project, the distribution package must be launched from `file://` so I need to inline all images declared inside css.

So the starting css

```css
   background: url(img/hello.png) no-repeat fixed center;
```

must be converted to

```css
   background: url(data:image/png;base64,R0lGODl....) no-repeat fixed center;
```

is this possible from `npm run build`?
I've found some (not working) solution using webpack

If possible also SVG assets should be converted to data uri

Comment: That's going to be one heavy CSS file if you inline *everything*, but you can look at [postcss-image-inliner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-image-inliner?activeTab=readme).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen thank you very much, after some problem with the config finally I've inlined svg files